# 2-Version software: Best VCS approach?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I suppose I'd better explain my situation:

I'm in the process of developing some software, and I'm at the stage where I'd like to split my project into two branches which differ in features. It so happens that this application is an Android application which I will be deploying on the Market, which has the constraint that every app must have a unique package identifier (sensible, no?).

My current approach has been to clone the git repo of my original project, but this causes issues with package names. I want the system to be robust enough so that a bugfix/new feature on one branch will merge into another branch, but only when I want it to.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think you meant VCS (version control system), not CMS.

Comment: Damned acronyms! Updated. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but it sounds like a plugin architecture might help.
You could ship your product with various sets of plugins depending on the features you want to include.

Comment: I actually have no idea how plugins work with Android. It's not a bad idea, but will probably require some learning.

Comment: This is definitely an issue that many Android developers have ran into, I like the idea of one code base and then being bale to conditionally compile separate version such as a free/demo version of a game and the paid version.  Since the android market uses the full package name for listings you have to actually have 2 separate packages in order to list 2 different versions of an app.  I ended up forking my code and now maintain 2 versions in svn and it is definitely a pain so I am looking forward to seeing suggestions on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handle that exact case myself for a paid app and trial version that have the same codebase.  I am using SVN, but any version control software that supports branching would work.

I created a branch for the trial version from the trunk.

Then I modified the trial verion's AndroidManifest.xml to change the package name, adding .trial on the end. I then had to also update all the activity java files to reference the correct R class.

My paid app package is com.hewittsoft.baby
My trial app package is com.hewittsoft.baby.trial

In my activities on the trial I branch I do this

```
import com.hewittsoft.baby.trial.R;
```

and that causes any references to R.id.textField (or whatever) to work.

After I did those steps I can develop on the main branch and then merge over any changes into the trial version without too much pain.

Comment: How did you deal with the differing file structures (ie: Launch.java is in /src/com/hewittsoft/baby/ in one and /src/com/hewittsoft/baby/trial/ in another)?

Comment: I don't have a different file structure.  All the activities and supporting code are still in /src/com/hewittsoft/baby/, and the AndroidManifest.xml still points to them, like this:
<activity android:name="com.hewittsoft.baby.WelcomeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

I do have a com/hewittsoft/baby/trial package but it just has code specific to the trial (checking if trial expired, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If the only issue is a packaging and release management issue, you could isolate those steps (rename the package, and test it in a target environment) from the historization cycle within one Git repo.

So you could go on, separate your development, one feature per branch, keeping the same package names for both (in order to easily merge fixes from one to another).
But then, to test and deploy one of those two versions, you could have a script in charge of renaming the packages, recompiling, packaging (jar) and deploying the result in the target test environment.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of very good articles on branching strategies:
http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/03/branching-strategies.html
http://nvie.com/git-model